# How to enable virtualization from BIOS in Gigabyte 970A DS3P, windows 10

Tags: windows-10, intel, virtualization

I have tried looking everywhere but there seems to be no help at all regarding enabling virtualization in Win 10.
Moreover, Gigabyte 970A DS3P support is also not helping.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You have to be more explicit. What do you mean with virtualization? And why the `vtk` tag?

Comment: I meant to include vtx tag. Its a mistake , let me change it

Answer (score 1):

Really late to the party here but someone else might need this...

To check if your CPU has Hyper-V support (and many other things) you can run coreinfo.exe written by Mark Russinovich / Sysinternals and available via MS website. It lists support for "Hypervisor" at the top of all the things it reports.

Answer (score -1):

To enable Virtualization (Hyper-V) in Windows 10 you need to turn on the feature. Check out this post https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/quick_start/walkthrough_install

On the bios side. I'm not sure about the 970a. I do have a Gigabyte board and it is in the advanced section of the bios setup. I could depend on your chipset and CPU. You need a newer chipset and a supported CPU to do virtualization

Comment: I have gone through the steps in the link that u shared. Its not helping :(

Comment: So Hyper-V is running? ... is it safe to say you have checked to see if your chipset is supported?

Comment: Yes it ran, completed the whole set up and restarted. But no use. How do I check for the chipset support?